# unpacking binary file using struct.unpack VS np.frombuffer VS np.ndarray VS np.fromfile

Tags: python, numpy, struct

I am unpacking large binary files (~1GB) with many different datatypes.  I am in the early stages of creating the loop to covert each byte.
I have been using struct.unpack, but recently thought it would run faster if I utilized numpy.  However switching to numpy has slowed down my program.
I have tried:

```
struct.unpack
np.fromfile
np.frombuffer
np.ndarray
```

*note:in the np.fromfile method I leave the file open and don't load it into memory and seek through it*

1)

```
with open(file="file_loc" , mode='rb') as file: 
    RAW = file.read()
byte=0
len = len(RAW)
while( byte < len):
    header = struct.unpack(">HHIH", RAW[byte:(byte+10)])
    size = header[1]
    loc  = str(header[3])
    data[loc] = struct.unpack(">B", RAW[byte+10:byte+size-10)
    byte+=size
```

2)

```
dt=('>u2,>u2,>u4,>u2')
with open(file="file_loc" , mode='rb') as RAW:
    same loop as above:
        header = np.fromfile(RAW[byte:byte+10], dtype=dt, count=1)[0]
        data   = np.fromfile(RAW[byte+10:byte+size-10], dtype=">u1", count=size-10)
```

3)

```
dt=('>u2,>u2,>u4,>u2')
with open(file="file_loc" , mode='rb') as file:
    RAW = file.read()
same loop:
    header = np.ndarray(buffer=RAW[byte:byte+10], dtype=dt_header, shape= 1)[0]
    data   = np.ndarray(buffer=RAW[byte+10:byte+size-10], dtype=">u1", shape=size-10)
```

4) `pretty much the same as 3 except using np.frombuffer()`

All of the numpy implementations process at about half the speed as the struct.unpack method, which is not what I expected.

Let me know if there is anything I can do to improve performance.

also, I just typed this from memory so it might have some errors.

Comment: Why do you expect the `fromfile` to be any better?   Each `fromfile` call is processing the same size block as the corresponding `struct.unpack`.  I assume the `data` blocks are larger than the `header` ones.  The unpacking is as simple as it gets, one byte per element.

Comment: In general, once you have created a `ndarray`, the processing is quite fast, at least for whole array operations that use compiled code, and various forms of indexing.  But creating an array, whether from lists, or from a file isn't necessarily fast.  Here file reading could be as big a time consumer as the processing.

Comment: yes, the `data` blocks are much bigger, and size defined in the headers.
I would expect the `data = np.frombuffer()` to be at least as fast as `data = struct.unpack`

Comment: I think the `unpack` statement should be: `struct.unpack( f'{size-10}B', RAW[byte+10: byte+size)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `struct` much, but between your code and docs I got it to work on a buffer that stores an array of integers.

Make a byte array/string from a `numpy` array.

```
In [81]: arr = np.arange(1000)
In [82]: barr = arr.tobytes()
In [83]: type(barr)
Out[83]: bytes
In [84]: len(barr)
Out[84]: 8000
```

The reverse is `tobytes`:

```
In [85]: x = np.frombuffer(barr, dtype=int)
In [86]: x[:10]
Out[86]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [87]: np.allclose(x,arr)
Out[87]: True
```

`ndarray` also works, though the direct use of this constructor is usually discouraged:

```
In [88]: x = np.ndarray(buffer=barr, dtype=int, shape=(1000,))
In [89]: np.allclose(x,arr)
Out[89]: True
```

To use `struct` I need to create a format that includes the length, "1000 long":

```
In [90]: tup = struct.unpack('1000l', barr)
In [91]: len(tup)
Out[91]: 1000
In [92]: tup[:10]
Out[92]: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
In [93]: np.allclose(np.array(tup),arr)
Out[93]: True
```

So now that we've established equivalent methods of reading the buffer, do some timings:

```
In [94]: timeit x = np.frombuffer(barr, dtype=int)
617 ns ± 0.806 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [95]: timeit x = np.ndarray(buffer=barr, dtype=int, shape=(1000,))
1.11 µs ± 1.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [96]: timeit tup = struct.unpack('1000l', barr)
19 µs ± 38.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [97]: timeit tup = np.array(struct.unpack('1000l', barr))
87.5 µs ± 25.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`frombuffer` looks pretty good.

Your `struct.unpack` loop confuses me.  I don't think it's doing the same thing as the `frombuffer`. But like said at the start, I haven't used `struct` much.